# Nightclubs in Friedrichshain

Tags: germany, berlin, nightlife

I am wondering what the nearest party clubs to Niederbarnimstrasse (in Berlin) are. Any type of clubs are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly you have [Revaler Straße 99](http://www.tip-berlin.de/musik-und-party/partymeile-revaler-strasse) very very close. This is the former rail repair shop and now populated with nightclubs, galeries and such. There are at least four nightclubs within that.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to check out [the club map](http://www.theclubmap.com/club-map/) – it shows clubs that may be closer than you think, especially around Friedrichshain and Kreuzberg.